# Create function with unknown number of std::array

Tags: c++11, templates, stdarray

I am trying to make a function that pass that test:

```
TEST(MyCat, CheckOn2Arrays){
    std::array<float, 3> vec1{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
    std::array<float, 3> vec2{4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};

    std::array<float, 6> r = MyCat(vec1, vec2);

    EXPECT_EQ(r[0], 1.0f);
    EXPECT_EQ(r[1], 2.0f);
    EXPECT_EQ(r[2], 3.0f);
    EXPECT_EQ(r[3], 4.0f);
    EXPECT_EQ(r[4], 5.0f);
    EXPECT_EQ(r[5], 6.0f);
}
```

I have writen that function:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
auto MyCat((std::array<T, N>) ... arrays) ->
decltype(std::array<T, N*sizeof...(arrays)>) {

    std::array<T, sizeof...(arrays)*N> retArray;

    int i = 0;
    for(std::array<T, N> array: arrays){
        T* = array.begin();
        while(!T){
            retArray[i] = &T;
            i++;
            T++;
        }
    }

    return retArray;
}
```

The function must take an arbitrary number of arguments and return an object of type std::array. All arguments are of type std::array (T and N are the same for all function arguments).

Im getting that errors and cant understand how to solve them..

```
../src/test/../myproject/MyCat.h:4:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
auto MyCat((std::array<T, N>) ... arrays) ->
                            ^
../src/test/../myproject/MyCat.h:4:6: warning: variable templates only available with     
std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
auto MyCat((std::array<T, N>) ... arrays) ->
     ^
../src/test/../myproject/MyCat.h:4:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘->’ token
auto MyCat((std::array<T, N>) ... arrays) ->
                                          ^
../src/test/MyCat_test.cc: In member function ‘virtual void     
MyCat_CheckOn2Arrays_Test::TestBody()’:
../src/test/MyCat_test.cc:10:35: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
std::array<float, 6> r = MyCat(vec1, vec2);
```

Comment: Simply put, you can't have a `...` in the function parameters (well, in the variadic template sense) without having a `...` in the template parameters. But the rest of your code is also some imaginary syntax - I don't know how you came up with that. I would recommend writing small pieces at a time that work and moving forward like that, instead of one big chunk of code full of fundamental problems. You won't be able to get the latter to compile without asking on SO every time...

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yes. it is.

Comment: It is better to state this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **a C++17 way** to do it, but I don't consider it pretty:

```
template<class T, std::size_t ... N>
auto MyCat(std::array<T, N> ... arrays)
{
    constexpr std::size_t NSum = (N + ...);
    std::array<T, NSum> retArray;

    auto outIt = retArray.begin();
    ((outIt = std::copy(arrays.begin(), arrays.end(), outIt)), ...);

    return retArray;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ha9NSY

This function takes any number of `std::array`s with the same type but potentially different sizes. (You could disallow different sizes if you wanted, left as exercise to the reader.)

We compute the total size (by summing all `N` in a fold expression) at compile-time (`constexpr`) and then create a return array of that size.

Next, the ugly part: We want to perform some operation for every variadic argument, so we use a fold expression on the comma operator. We want to copy the current variadic argument (`arrays`) to the correct section of `retArray`. Thankfully, `std::copy` returns an updated iterator for the output, so we can use that to keep track of where to copy to. Note that you need parenthesis around both the comma-operated expression (the iterator assignment) and around the whole fold expression.

It works, but again, not pretty. And it's not even `constexpr` (because `std::copy` is not `constexpr`)...

Comment: In tags i've written, that I'm using c++11. Your code does not work with it.

Comment: True. Added a note.